# Margin-top not working for <p> and <a> tag?

Tags: html, css, margin

I have been trying to implement margin-top for a link button but it doesn't work at all. I have also tried inline styles for both 'p' and 'a' tag.

There are 3 li elements, i haven't posted whole code here as it is same as first li element.

HTML

```
<div id="services">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src="images/service.png" alt=""/>
            <p class="service-heading">Service 1</p>
            <p>Amet nisi porttitor enim parturient, cras! Odio pulvinar a cras? Sit sociis. Augue tempor mid rhoncus nec nisi ac pulvinar dictumst</p>
            <p><a href="#">Read More</a></p> 
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the css code for the above html.
css code:

```
#services{
    background-color: #afc1ff;
    height: 490px;
    padding: 5%;
    border-top: 5px solid #4972ff;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #4972ff;
}
 #services ul{
/*  background-color: red; */
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding: 0 0 0 50px;
}
#services ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 22%;
    padding: 1%;
    margin: 0 4% 0 4%;
    color: #4c4c4c;
    font-size: 14px; font-size: 1.4rem;
    text-align: center;
} 
.service-heading{
    font-size: 18px; font-size: 1.8rem;
}
#services ul li a{
    background-color: #4972ff;
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #779bff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 8px;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 100, accepted):

This issue is known as [Margin Collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin_collapsing) and happens sometimes between `top` and `bottom` margins on block elements.

> The margins of adjacent siblings are collapsed

That's why the margin doesn't work on the `p` tag. To make it work here an option is to use `padding-top` on the p tag.

And on the `a` tag the margin doesn't work because it's an inline element. You may need to change its `display` property to `inline-block` or `block`.

Comment: For those confused *and* in disagreement, you *are* correct. Programming deals with **literal interpretation**, collapsed-margins is a *human-enforced bug* to **conceptually imply** instead of **literally interpret**. However it will eventually be removed from the specification when fully competent people take control over the standards.

Comment: Found this article by Googling — I had the same issue, but your use of `display: inline-block` proved to be the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 24):

The `<a>` tag is an inline element and therefore cannot have a top or bottom margin. But you can solve this by applying `display: inline-block;` to it.

Answer (score 3):

the link tag `<a>` is inline block tags and it means it must be in one line beside other elements and should has a parent part that the parent part determines how much these inline-block elements should have margin top and button 
there's two ways to do that:
convert theme to block:

```
#services a{
display: block;
margin-top: 8px;
}
```

or simply you can work with its `padding`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
#services ul li a{
    background-color: #4972ff;
    color: #fff;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #779bff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 8px;
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to set a margin on an `<a>` tag without first setting it to `display:block;`.

In your case, you need to do something like this:

```
#services ul li p {
padding: 8px;
margin-top: 10px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue only margin left and roght worked 
solved it by changing the display to flex

Answer (score 0):

```
position: absolute;
/* This css code may help you.*/
```

Comment: Where does it go?