# Why is margin not working for <p> element?

Tags: html, css

I want to specify margins for all `p` elements in my html/php page. It should be straightforward, but it doesn't work for me. Please excuse my noob level.

Here is my css code I added to the `head`:

```
<style>
p {
    margin-left: 120px;
    margin-right: 120px;
}

.code {
    color : blue;
    background-color: lightgrey
}

.center {
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
```

In the body I have `p` elements, none of which has a margin.In `body` Example:

```
<a name="hardware"></a>
    <h4>Required hardware:</h4>
    <p>
        I tested this procedure on a Raspberry Pi 3B+, having 1 GB of RAM.
    </p>
```

Does anyone know why the left/right margin is not working?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Margin-top not working for <p> and <a> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20975091/margin-top-not-working-for-p-and-a-tag)

Comment: Please share your HTML code as well or add a fiddle.

Comment: How do you know the `p` elements don't have margins?

Answer (score -1):

I see that margins added.

Maybe because of added class `center` to `p` you don't see. If you provide us with more code, it will be clearer.

To illustrate the idea I made snippet, look inti it.

P.S. useful to know, `margin` in `css` between siblings not added but the bigger `margin` wins. You can see in snippet, that `p` has default `top` and `bottom` `margin`, but sibling `p`s have gap between them which equals to one of `margin`'s value, not `margin-bottom` + `marging-top` values.

```css
.margins {
  margin-left: 120px;
  margin-right: 120px;
}
.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.p-border p {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.border-dot {
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<div class="border-dot">
  <p class="center margins">With margins</p>
  <p class="center margins">With margins</p>
  <p class="center">Without margins</p>
</div>

<div class="border-dot p-border">
  <p class="center margins">With margins</p>
  <p class="center margins">With margins</p>
  <p class="center">Without margins</p>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you. Still, the  text started at pixel 0 on the left, it is not centered. I couldn't find the issue so I defined a CSS class with margin and used it in all ```<p>```` elements. It's not very elegant, but I solved it quicker this way.